# Workaround to enable form validation on views dynamically loaded by ajax on Asp.Net Mvc3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

That's a very common bug that happens to people who load a partial view via ajax and that view has a model with DataAnnotation validators. When u load the View the validation stop working.

How to fix that?

Comment: This is a blog post, not a question.  You should edit the question into an actual question, then post an answer.

Comment: I know. But i can't answer my own question since i'm new member. I need like 100 points of reputation. Anyways, just wanted to share. Maybe it can help someone else.

Comment: Greate! but what should we do when the unobtrusive is not enabled?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.get("url", function()
{
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#form-id");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@Mahmoud Moravej

I don't know if this is part of unobtrusive or not, but you can use

```
        $("form").validate({
            rules: {
                textbox1Id: "required",
                textbox2Id: "required"
            },
            messages: {
                textbox1Id: "*",
                textbox2Id: "omg you missed textbox2!"
            }
        });
```