# Partial View and Validation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have tried the many solutions online for trying to get validation to work when loading a partial view, but none of them seemed to work.

I currently have some jQuery code which looks like:

```
$(".alert").click(function () {
    $("#add-comics-container").load("/ManageComics/ComicEditor", function () {
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#add-comics-container");
    });
    $("#add-comics-container").fadeIn();
    $(".blackout").css("display", "block");
    return false;
});
```

My /ManageComics/ComicEditor looks like:

```
public ActionResult ComicEditor() {
    return PartialView("_ComicEditorPartial");
}
```

My Partial more or less looks like:

```
@model Comics.Models.LocalComicModel
@Html.BeginForm("Index", "ManageComics", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "addComicForm", value = "1"}){ 

<div class="add-comics-item">
   <div class="add-comics-left">
      <span class="add-comics-title bold_text">@Html.LabelFor(u => u.Title)</span>
      <div class="add-comics-help">WebComic Title throughout website</div>
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Title)
   </div>
   <div class="add-comics-right">
      @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Title)
   </div>
</div>

}
```

Comment: Discussed many times earlier... you can check this: here http://stackoverflow.com/a/9324173/690329 or here http://stackoverflow.com/q/7908169/690329

Comment: I have tried that solution and it does not seem to work for me. I have tried many of the ones that I searched on google and none of those worked as well. This was a last resort.

Comment: Did you try the first solution?

Comment: I tried both of them.

Comment: Where did you try it? It's not in your code.

Comment: I finally found the solution. I was supposed to add this to my global.aspx file:
    `DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;`